# Setting Date format for autoprop 'DATE' in SVN

Tags: date, svn, tortoisesvn

I have some files that use the autoproperty `$Date` of SVN.

When some colleagues in France do a checkout of the repository, the date is in French. When they do the verification of checksum, these files are KO because of this difference of format for the date.

*Note: we are using Windows and our client of choice is TortoiseSVN but are open to use command line clients.*

**Question 1**: Is there any way to force the format for the date during the checkout?

We tried the following:

- Setting "English" in Tortoise SVN
- Setting environment variable `LANG` to `EN_US` and doing a checkout with both TortoiseSVN and svn commandline

None of these solutions is working.

**Question 2**: Would the time zone impact the date in the header as well?

Thanks

---

*NB: This is the header of our source code, for what it matters.*

```
/*==============================================================================================
 *  FILENAME          : Source.h
 *  VERSION           : $Revision: 85911 $
 *  MODIFICATION DATE : $Date: 2015-06-12 18:26:22 +0800 (Fri, 12 Jun 2015) $
 *============================================================================================*/
```

Answer (score 3):

**A1**: I don't know, how to manipulate locale-setting in Windows in *easy and automated style* - inspired by [this old answer in Subversion maillist](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-01/0449.shtml) - (better to ask it SU) and can suggest now only dirty hack: import reg-files for FR and EN locales before and after checkout (how to prepare: switch to FR in Control Panel, save `Current Control Set` part of registry, return to EN, save CCS again, leave in .reg only mutable part), checkout in bat-file only (change locale around checkout)

**A2**: Sad, but yes

```
$Date: 2015-06-19 19:45:22 +0500 (Пт, 19 июн 2015) $
```

inserts not only language-specific date (trailing part), but also TZ of client

**1.8.*-specific solution**: you can create and use replacement for `$Date` keyword, which use UTC-time instead of local (as `$Id` do for time-part now) with %d variable it it

```
>svn pl -v file.txt
Properties on 'file.txt':
  svn:keywords
    Author Date Id Revision URL Header IntDate=%d
```

and IntDate will expand location-independent

```
$IntDate: 2015-06-19 14:45:22Z $
```